# Foreign key constraint fail in recursive table using MySQL 5.6 and GORM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to add a foreign key in recursive Table and enable `onDelete` `onUpdate` `CASCADE` mode to delete all children when parent is deleted (same with update).

I am using go 1.11.4 with gorm as ORM and MySQL 5.6

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
)

type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string 
  Child   *User `gorm:"Foreignkey:Parent"` 
  Parent *uint
}

func main() {
  db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "root@/testdb")
  if err != nil {
    panic("failed to connect database")
  }
  defer db.Close()

  // Migrate the schema
  db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
  db.Model(&User{}).AddForeignKey("parent","users(id)","CASCADE","CASCADE")

  // Create
  u := User{Name: "Parent"}
  db.Save(&u)

  u2 := User{Name: "Child", Parent: &u.ID}
  db.Save(&u2)

}
```

#### I got this error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I updated this code and it works finally

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string 
  Child   *User `gorm:"Foreignkey:Parent"` 
  Parent uint   `sql:"type:bigint REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE"`
}
```

I've had trouble using `AddForeignKey()` but hardcoding it like that seems to work.

Comment: I updated my code and it works with addForeignKey() , parent must be created before child and also foreign key named Parent must *uint it accept NULL value by default (when parent is created)